# Change navbar height in Bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to reduce the height of `Bootstrap3`'s fixed navbar. I found the `@navbar-height` variable in variable. less, and changed it, but it doesn't seem to change anything.
I also tries these solutions: "[Change navbar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612314/change-navbar-height)", "[Navbar height changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146773/navbar-height-changing)". No result.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code to your question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**update**

As per response on https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11443 @mdo wrote:

> Change the `@navbar-height` and `@navbar-padding-vertical` and you
>   should get it.

Example, set `@navbar-height:                    20px;` and `@navbar-padding-vertical:          0;`, see: http://bootply.com/100604

Note this doesn't set the height of the `.navbar-form` elements

**end update**

The navbar itself has no defined width. Cause Bootstrap use the [border-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854259/why-did-bootstrap-3-switch-to-box-sizing-border-box/18858771) model, the height is set by the highest element inside it.

Notice the navbar will have a min-height (set to 50px the default 
navbar height). @navbar-height in navbar.less sets this min-height.

also read it's comments:

> // Ensure a navbar always shows (e.g., without a .navbar-brand in collapsed mode)

To change the height you will have to change the heights of the inside 
elements.

### .navbar-brand

The .navbar-brand class got a height of 50px. Defined by a padding of 
15px + a line-height of 20px;. (2 x 15 + 20 = 50).

The line-height is set in navbar.less too by @line-height-computed.
With @line-height-computed defined in variables.less as 
`floor(@font-size-base * @line-height-base); // ~20px`

@line-height-computed will also used in forms, navigation, etc. so 
changing it and recompile Bootstrap will not only effect your navbar.

The above make it impossible to set your navbar height with Less.

The padding is defined by `navbar-padding-vertical` but this variables is NOT used for setting the padding of the navbar links (.navbar-nav > li > a)

Use css to manipulate the line-height (so font-size) and padding of 
.navbar-brand to change its height and so the height of the navbar.

### .navbar-nav > li > a

The .navbar-nav > li > a class, the links in your navbar also defines 
a height of 50px (padding of 15 bottom/top) and a line-height of 20x 
again.
Note the padding is first set to 10px hard code in navbar.less and 
overwritten by `((@navbar-height - @line-height-computed) / 2)` (higher precedence) for  `@media (min-width: 
@grid-float-breakpoint)`

Also in this case the line-height of the links will be set by 
@line-height-computed.

### Other elements

Also element like forms, dropdown will have a calculated height.

Overall it seems you will have to use css for the different elements 
of your fixed navbar to sets it's height.

See also: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11443 and https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11444

Comment: In your CSS override `.nav-bar { min-height: xpx)`, set x = to whatever value you want the height to be.  Then, additionally override `.navbar-brand,.navbar-nav>li>a { padding-top: ypx; padding-bottom: ypx }` where y = (x [your new min-height value] - 50 [default nav bar min-height] / 2) + 15 [default padding-top, padding-bottom] values.

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar {
    padding: 0;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, padding 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 10px;
    line-height: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

It should override scrolling-nav.css