# How to change navbar size in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-frameworks

I am trying to increase [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) 3.0 navbar height which is used with fixed top behavior.

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 - Height of the NavBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651237/bootstrap-3-height-of-the-navbar)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the .less or .scss version, you can edit the following `$navbar-height` variable in code:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L360

If not, you need to override it with a rule by statiing:

```
.navbar {
    height: {new height};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it is hard to help but in `Bootstrap 3` typically,

This is the `less` variable `@navber-height` and `@navbar-padding-vertical` will adjust the height of the navbar.

But in my current Bootstrap app I have it set up different using

```
header.navbar {
    height: 54px;
}
```

The easiest thing to do would be to `inspect element` on the navigation bar then look at the `css` to see where the `height` value is. Adjust it to the desired `height`.

Then create a rule in your `css` with `!important` to override the existing `Bootstrap` `css`.

This is another example without `less`.

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    height: 70px !important; /* Whatever you want. */
}
```

Create new `css` file and put your overrides in it.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/overrides.css'/>
```

inside `overrides.css`

If this css rule exists inside `Bootstrap` when you inspect element then override it in the overrides css file you have added now.

remember use `!important`

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    height: 70px !important; /* Whatever you want. */
}
```

Comment: witch css file should I edit in My Bootstrap css folder?

Comment: I create a new css file. The put it below the bootstrap css file in the head of your document. That way anything you override is sure to stick! I updated my answer to show you what I meen. If this helps you please accept. If not please let me know why and I will try and help more.

Comment: @wunu I did not clear about your comment. but did you mean should I change bootstrap.css file .navbar-fixed-top?