# Bootstrap changing navigation bar height for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I've managed to change the height for the navigation bar when width is more than 768px from 50px to 80px. When I look at it via mobile, it goes back to 50px. How do I go about changing the height and centering the menu icon according to the height?

Here's what I did to change the height

```
.navbar {
    min-height:80px !important;
}
```

All help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change `@navbar-height` and `@navbar-padding-vertical`

[visit this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890700/change-navbar-height-in-bootstrap3)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But i cant find any of the two in bootstrap.min.css. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the links. The problem is I cant find navbar-height or navbar-padding-vertical in the links you sent me. is there a more specific way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you try this?

```
.navbar {
    min-height:50px !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        min-height:80px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, That changed the mobile version of the navbar to 50px. I managed to change it to 80px, but on clicking the menu icon, the dropdown starts after 50px. i need it to start after 80px. Any ideas? Thanks